# How prove this $Z(H)\neq 1$, if for any $g\in G\setminus H, H\cap H^g=1$

Tags: group-theory

Let $2||H|$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, $H\le G$, such that for any $g\in G\setminus H$ the following holds. $$H\cap H^g=1$$

> Show  that :$$Z(H)\neq 1$$ where $Z(H)$ is center of the $H$.

This problem is from China book: *Limited group theory guidance* (this book is our teacher assigned homework).

I can't prove it.

I want use Frobenius threom to solve it, but I can't do it.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use big symbols for binary operations. Anyway, do you have any ideas / thoughts / work / context you can share thus far?

Comment: @whacka,I have edit my idea,

Comment: Is "for any" = "for every" or "for some"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen,it's meaning  for every

Answer (score 1):

By the Frobenius Theorem, $G$ has a normal subgroup $K$, disjoint from $H$. Since $|H|$ is even, it has an element $t$ of order $2$. By the assumption on $H$, $t$ does not centralize any nontrivial element of $K$. So $t$ induces a fixed-point-free automorphism of $K$ which implies that $t^{-1}kt = k^{-1}$ for all $k \in K$. (That is a standard result.) Since this is true for all elements of order $2$ in $H$, $t$ must be the uniaue such element, so $t \in Z(H)$ and hence $Z(H) \ne 1$.